# Executar comando como Admin c#

Tags: c#

Vou direto ao ponto! Tenho uma aplicação em C# e preciso executar um comando no Cmd com privilégio de Admin. Preciso ativar o SQL Server caso ele esteja parado.

```
public List<Atendimento> Pesquisar()
    {
        try
        {
            using (CasaVipEntities objEntity = new CasaVipEntities())
            {
                var result = objEntity.Atendimento.GroupBy(c => c.Cliente).ToList();
                return result.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();

            }
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException) 
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

            Process myProcess = new Process();

            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

            myProcess.Start();

            StreamWriter myStreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput;
            myStreamWriter.WriteLine("net start MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS");
            myStreamWriter.Close();
            myProcess.WaitForExit();
            myProcess.Close();

        }
```

Não sei porque não está ativando o SQL Server. Se eu abrir o cmd normalmente e digitar o comando ele ativa, mas pele aplicação não. Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar o seguinte comando:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

Comment: Sem sucesso. O prompt abre mas executa o comando

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer de forma alternativa, com que chama o prompt já com o comando para executar:

```
  Process myProcess = new Process();

  myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
  myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
  myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c \"net start MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\"";

  myProcess.Start();
  myProcess.WaitForExit();
  // myProcess.Close(); -- não é necessário
```

Deste jeito, o parâmetro `/c` já irá informar o comando a ser executado. E o verbete `RunAs` irá indicar que o processo requer elevação.